# Why do i get SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing when i run this code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
    s = input(' Enter a monomial: ')
    coeff, power = s.partition('x^')
    print('{}x^{}'.format(int(coeff) * int(power), int(power) - 1)
```

I do not know what else is needed at the end of this code. Is there something that needs to be added in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not closing `print` function, one a close parenthesis at the end is missing. I suggest you to use some `linter` to debug and find warning and errors. The final code should be as below:

```
s = input(' Enter a monomial: ')
coeff, power = s.partition('x^')
print('{}x^{}'.format(int(coeff) * int(power), int(power) - 1))
```

Comment: That worked!!!. However when i ran the code I ended up with these errors:                                                                                                         Enter a monomial: 2x^12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./derivative.py", line 4, in <module>
    coeff, power = s.partition('x^')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Yep, that makes sense because partition is splitting the input in 3 parts and you're capturing just two of those `coeff, power`. You can use `split` function instead and the replace that line as following: `coeff, power = s.split('x^')`

Comment: That worked like a charm!!! Results have been achieved. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You're welcome, we're here to help each other. Don't forget try to implement a `linter` e.g. `pylint` to make debugging easier and you don't face this error next time :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a bracket in last line:

```
print('{}x^{}'.format(int(coeff) * int(power), int(power) - 1))
```